# ReadyNAS 316 and Samba

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, samba

Can/Will anyone please help with setting up Samba correctly on Ubuntu 16.04? I have been through several posts on various forums, and have installed the server, the client, a few other things that proved completely useless, followed various instructions for editing the smb.conf and still I cannot find anything that will....

Just make it go.

Of course, I want to share files between machines. But, primarily need samba to "see" the home shares on the ReadyNAS 316. Nautilus can connect. It can see the server in the workgroup. And, it can even see the other folders in the /data/ directory... 
But, neither the "home" folder not any of the shares in the home folder can be seen. I can use samba to connect to the ReadyNAS from any number of other machines (mainly OS X) even my ipad will connect to the server. home folder access is not a problem from any other OS...

But, Linux refuses to do this seemingly basic task.

This seems to me to be one of the things that should be just a matter of setting up the path... user... and pass... But, that has definitely proven to NOT be the case with any of the networking stratgies in Linux... so far. NFS,SMB,AFP have all been impossible for me to set up. So, yeah... I have ONE handful of hair left after all the pulling. Please help me save it.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your router, or the NAS, also act as a wins server? If so, edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and set up your wins server address to point at your router/NAS box. Change `;   wins server = w.x.y.z` to `wins server = 192.168.1.1` (change to the correct router/NAS address). Run `testparm` when you're done editing, to check your smb.conf file.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of using the router that way. I'm fairly certain that the NAS cannot be set up as a WINS server. But, my ASUS AC3200 should... I will try tonight and get back with results.

Comment: No. It appears that the ASUS router with Merlin-WRT can not act as a WINS server. Back to square one.

Comment: Then try setting one of your computers as win server. Edit smb.conf # WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no (uncomment and change to yes)
Report back.

Comment: I'm sorry to have provided such incomplete information. It is hard for me to know what is important.
I already had the wins support = yes and set the wins server to the IP of the NAS... When that didn't get the result I wanted, I changed the wins server IP to the linux host machine (standalone server mode) running samba-server (local).
I did get another entry in my "Network Servers" main window. But, it did not respond any differently than the others. And, the behaviour of the entry in the "workgroup" also saw no change. this is after restarting the NAS and the local machine in each case.

Comment: I'm no Samba expert... yet... but according to the smb.conf file, you can't have a computer be BOTH a wins server and a wins client at the same time. So you can't say `wins support=yes` **and** `wins server=n.n.n.n` at the same time. It's one or the other. I could be wrong. Try it and report back.

Comment: Ahh. The new entrie in Network Servers is (somehow) using AFP protocol... So, it doesn't have any relevance to the Samba issue.
THANKS SO MUCH for offering assistance. I really need it with this problem.

Comment: You lost me. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the IP address (hashed it out). And, restarted everything. There is no (noticeable) change in the behavior of the workgroup entries.
I'm not sure about the situation of Server/Client coexistence on the same machine. Another piece of the puzzle to find.

Comment: Not sure which point to clarify... I tried your previous suggestion. But, there was no change in behaviour after hashing-out (#) the IP entry and restarting.
The "new" entry in the Network Server window from my earlier comment was likely because several Macs were started on the same network. AFP is what we usually use around here. I didn't know Linux could access AFP without installing it.

Comment: Hopefully somebody else can chime in with some more Samba experience. Please keep me informed if you get it all going (by placing @heynnema in the beginning of a new comment).

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your help!... and for telling me how to directly address people here. Hopefully, we can solve this and learn something from it. <LOL>

Comment: @heynnema - I am not presented with the option to mark your response as "helpful". I don't know why.  
But, I would, if I could.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about me. If I had put any thoughts into a formal answer, you could have voted/accept from there. But we never got your problem solved... so maybe next time I can help more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution found and cobbled together from many different posts on many different forums...

The problem was in smb.conf of course.

The main solution was to make one machine a WINS server. (Thanks @heynnema) But, the [global] section of smb.conf had many small other details which cleared the initial problem and several other niggling issues. 
What is provided here is a starting point for anyone fighting to get samba working.

1) navigate to /etc/hosts file and enter the IP and hostname of every system in the workgroup into the hosts file...

2) Edit smb.conf to look something similar to this:

netbios name = NAME_OF_SYSTEM

workgroup = WORKGRP_NAME ##(Same for every machine/device)

name resolve order = wins hosts bcast lmhosts

security = user

encrypt passwords = yes

smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd ## (create this file)

interfaces = xxx.yyy.zzz.www/Yy etho ##(THIS system's IP/mask 8,12 or 24 depending on the subnet mask)

bind interfaces only = yes

hostname lookups = yes

server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

os level = 99

wins support = yes ## (Only on the machine which is acting as the server)

domain master = yes ## (Only on the machine which is acting as the server)

preferred master = yes ## (Only on the machine which is acting as the server)

wins server = xxx.yyy.zzz.www ##(only on the CLIENT MACHINES.. Remark this on the WINS server)

server role = standalone server

unix password sync = yes

### OK then

3) create your shares...

[share_name]

comment = "WHATEVER YOU WANT"

path = /home/USERNAME ## just as an example

writeable = yes

browseable = yes

valid users = USERNAME

4) THEN.... Create your user and enable the account on all systems

sudo smbpasswd -L -a USERNAME ## This one creates the user

sudo smbpasswd -L -e USERNAME ## this one enables the user

#### #

This is what I did... And, it now works for me. I hope this saves someone else all the trouble I had finding, reading, and figuring this out... It is a great starting point for putting samba to work for you.

ENJOY